# Relaxed atomics and the reorder buffer

Tags: c++11, memory, cpu, cpu-cache

Modern processors execute instructions out of order as per [Tomasulo algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomasulo_algorithm), so the purpose of the [reorder buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-order_buffer) is to ensure that the *results of the instructions* are written out *in program order* via its ISSUE and COMMIT pointers.  So if I have instructions X, Y, Z, the actual execution order could be Y, Z, X but the order any results are written back in (committed/retired) is X, Y, Z.

Now, I am confused as to how this ties in with C++11 relaxed atomics.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering) tells me firstly that (emphasis mine)

> Memory ordering describes the order of accesses to computer memory by
> a CPU. The term can refer either to the memory ordering generated by
> the compiler during compile time, **or to the memory ordering generated
> by a CPU during runtime.**

...and that with relaxed consistency:

> Loads can be reordered after loads (for better working of cache coherency, better scaling)
>
> Loads can be reordered after stores
>
> Stores can be reordered after stores Stores can be reordered after loads

So I don't understand what relaxed atomics are actually giving me, since any instruction can be executed out-of-order, *but always has to be "committed/retired" in order as per the reorder buffer*.

**ASSUMPTION:** Surely it can't be that relaxed consistency allows the reorder buffer to *commit/retire instructions truly out-of-the-order that the assembly dictates* (since then why have the reorder buffer?), so the only thing I can think of - which I have read numerous times (and reasonably understand) - is that it affects the order that other cores "see" writes to memory locations in.  So as a simple example, a relaxed write to variable X on Core1 might not be immediately visible in Core2; whereas with an acquire/release or sequentially consistent write it will be.

---

**1)** Can someone clarify if my assumption here is correct?

**2)** When a "store word" instruction is retired by the reorder buffer, what is the difference on a hardware level in what happens when that store is "relaxed" versus when it is "sequentially consistent"?  It has got to be to do with the caches, surely?  Kind of "*when you feel like it, push this value out to other caches*" as opposed to "*push this out to all other caches now*" (or is that wrong?)

---

I have searched extensively for information on this before posting my question, FYI.

Comment: As far as memory ordering is concerned, relaxed atomics give you nothing over non-atomic variables. You only get the "atomic" aspect.

Comment: C++ `std::atomic` semantics don't really map 1:1 onto reorder buffer stores - they are quite different levels of abstraction (which becomes clear when considering that `std::atomic` may even employ locks where necessary). And Wikipedia's definition of memory ordering does not have to map onto the way `std::atomic` is specified to work. In other words, there would be no contradiction anywhere if `std::atomic` did nothing regarding out-of-order execution on the CPU. Just that "memory ordering" and related terms are mentioned for either does not mean the two interact in any way.

Comment: @j6t From the language semantics POV, you get much more than atomicity: you get the fact race conditions are just that, and not "data races" which are forbidden.